# MacBook Pro Latin American layout keyboard with USA keyboard configuration compatibility

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I decided to buy an Apple MacBook Pro in my country but the layout is a bit different from the English distribution. The only question I have is if I will have any problem with the keys <kbd>><</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Please check the picture attached, in the English keyboard instead of <kbd>Z</kbd> next to shift you have a <kbd>><</kbd> key. If I change the layout config on the computer with this keyboard, will <kbd>Z</kbd> work when I press the <kbd>><</kbd> key?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard you picture is the ISO type used in Europe and is standard for Spanish.  The Apple Latin American keyboard is slightly different:  It has no key printed with Ç (used in Catalan).

If you use it with the US Input Source active, the <> key will produce `~ (tilde and grave accent).

If you want the <> key to produce Z (so you would then have 2 keys which do that),  you would have make a custom keyboard layout with something like [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).